# Setting global variables and wrap in $(window).load

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I'm trying to set some Js variables that calculate some heights and offsets, but I need to do that after the page loads b/c I've got 3rd party ads loading and shifting things around.

So the issue:

What I've got is:

```
var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height(),
    sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
```

But those won't be set right unless I get them like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height(),
        sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

But the problem then is that those variables aren't global - they're local to that function and hence aren't reusable by other functions.

**So the question then**:   How can I set it up so these variables are set on window.load, but are still global and useable by other functions?

Comment: Why not just declare them on global scope and fill them on the onLoad? To accomplish that, you would just use your first example, without the assignment. And then, you would use the second example, without the var keyword (it would be just a value assignment to the vars declared on the global scope)

Comment: I prefer to be explicit `window['sidebarHeight']=…`, but I also capitalize my globals `SIDEBAR_HEIGHT`; also instead of `$(window).on('load'` you might want to do `$(document).on('load'`, since you're really after the document content has populated and not the browser window being opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare globally:

```
var sidebarHeight, sidebarOffset;
```

Set locally:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
    sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

They won't have a value between their declaration and setting them, so other code which uses them may need to account for that.  But if you need them to be in global scope then just declare them in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are bad practice and should be avoided!

For your question, setting them global is easy. You can just attach them to window, like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    window.sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
    window.sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

Or, just declare them globally:

```
var sidebarHeight, sidebarOffset;
$(window).on('load', function(){
    sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
    sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

But, I strongly recommend avoiding this and maybe consider using some name-spacing to your project, something like this:

```
var MY_PROJET_NAMESPACE = MY_PROJET_NAMESPACE || {};
$(window).on('load', function(){
    MY_PROJET_NAMESPACE.sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
    MY_PROJET_NAMESPACE.sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

This will prevent global namespace pollution (you will only have one global variable on the global scope)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that I can think of to accomplish that.

1st way:
  You just declare the variables on globalScope, but you don't assign any value. Then, at the onLoad you assign the value to them, just like this:

```
var sidebarHeight;
var sidebarOffset;
$(window).on('load', function(){
    sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
    sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

2nd way (me favourite):
  You can create an extra attribute on the window object itself. As the window object reference will be global, so will your extra attribute. Do it like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    window.sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
    window.sidebarOffset = $('.sidebar').offset().top;
});
```

And wherever you need that value again, you could read `window.sidebarHeight` or `window.sidebarOffset`.

Hope that helps.